# How do you use Split() on a hyphen?

Tags: vba

I have a string that contains "-" near the end.  I want to return everything to the left of that hyphen.

I don't know how to use Split() or Regex() to do that.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? The documentation of the Split function seems pretty clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two methods that handle removing the hyphen and a non-hyphen case

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim StrTest As String
    StrTest = "I have a hypen-somewhere"
    If InStr(StrTest, "-") > 0 Then
        MsgBox Left$(StrTest, InStr(StrTest, "-") - 1)
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Test2()
    Dim StrTest As String
    Dim vString
    StrTest = "I have a hypen-somewhere"
    vString = Split(StrTest, "-")
    If UBound(vString) > 0 Then
        MsgBox vString(0)
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combo of `Instr()`, `Mid()` and `Len()` [here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
Dim hyphenString As String = "hello-world"
Dim leftSide As String = Left(hyphenString, InStr(hyphenString, "-"))
```

`leftSide` should now contain "hello"

Comment: This retuns "hello-" not "hello". And returns nothing at all if there is no hypen

Comment: You need to use `Left(hyphenString, InStr(hyphenString, "-")-1)` to get everything left of the hyphen.